# Rails 2.3.8 application not booting after installing RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

After installing Rails 3, RVM and Ruby 1.9.2, I've been having trouble running this Rails 2.3.8 app.

```
necromancer@factory$ script/server
./script/../config/boot.rb:5: uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)
 from script/server:2:in `require'
 from script/server:2
```

After running `gem which rails`, I got the following path:

```
/Users/necromancer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails.rb
```

So I uninstalled railties-3.0.0 and ran `gem install rails` Now, `gem which rails` throws the following error:

```
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library rails
```

I also tried uninstalling rails 2.3.8 and running `bundle install` within my app. Then I tried to `gem uninstall rails` and `gem install rails -v=2.3.8`, and while the rails binary still works, `gem which rails` still throws this error. I think it may be the source of my problem...how do I get this to point to rails 2.3.8 on my rvm 1.8.7 gemset??

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have conflict with Rails 2 and Rails 3.

You have 2 choices:

- Use bundler in your rails 2.3 app
- Use an rvm gemset independant between your rails 2 and rails 3 application

Comment: I am using bundler in my Rails 2.3.8 app, and I ran "bundle install" with no problems. I still can not boot my app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gemsets, run rails --version and make sure it is installed. It looks like a Rails 3 vs Rails 2.x issue to me.

Gemsets will save your sanity if you are not using them already.

Comment: rails -v reports "Rails 2.3.8", and my Gemfile.lock reports: "rails, actionmailer, actionpack, activerecord, activeresource and activesupport" all @ 2.3.8

Comment: I did have a problem with Rails versions before and the only solution I could find was to uninstall Rails and reinstall the versions that I wanted through RVM. Hopefully someone has a better solution.